# How to discover IOS app's deep links?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I am trying to examine an IOS app so that I can link to it using deep links or universal links from a web page. Is there a utility to interrogate deep links or universal links from an app binary or an API? I looked here:

https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=564157241

but I don't see any indications of links.

All of the deep links that I've tried simply open the app's page in the app store, even though the app is installed on my iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without access to the original source code, you could attempt to contact the owners of the application to receive the details of their deep linking scheme. The details of the url formatting required for deep linking into an application is not publicly available for most apps to prevent unwanted parties providing unwanted links. In the most extreme case of need you could use a decompiler and reverse-engineer the links from the decompiled code.

Comment: This answers the question. I've provided the follow-on misfit-specific answer in another answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is no deep or universal link in the misfit app. However, the following will open the app:

https://github.com/davidthewatson/open_misfit_app_in_mobile_web_browser/blob/master/index.html

Tested on IOS 9.2 with the Misfit app.

The developer was kind enough to answer my question.

I've hosted the page here for testing:

http://davidwatson.org/open_misfit_app_in_mobile_web_browser/

Answer (score -1):

See [this](https://www.appsflyer.com/blog/how-to-set-up-ios-9-universal-links-for-your-app/) guide on how to set Universal Links